# Why does Transcrypt compilation not work inside a Python script with the line: os.system('python -m transcrypt -b -m -n <somePythonFile>.py')?

Tags: javascript, python, compilation, translation, transcrypt

I have a Python file translate2JS.py that I am trying to dynamically translate to JS after writing a Python function body to it. Here is the file CURRENTLY for the sake of illustrating the issue:

```
def tempFunc():
    for i in range(25):
         navigator.move("right")
```

I have the .py file (translate2JS.py) in a folder called translate2JS. I'm doing the following in a function of views.py of a Django project:

```
os.system('ls') #check initial directory
os.chdir('main/static/main/js/translate2JS')
os.system('ls') #check right directory
os.system('python -m transcrypt -b -m -n translate2JS.py')# THIS is creating an empty file but if the command is entered
# in terminal it works as intended...# also, may need to change python to python3.6 when uploading
os.chdir('../../../../../')
os.system('ls') # check right directory
```

I checked that my current working directory is correct, and the above line actually DOES create the .js file, but that file only contains the following:

```
// Transcrypt'ed from Python, 2018-10-24 00:01:12
import {AssertionError, AttributeError, BaseException, DeprecationWarning, Exception, IndexError, IterableError, KeyError, NotImplementedError, RuntimeWarning, StopIteration, UserWarning, ValueError, Warning, __JsIterator__, __PyIterator__, __Terminal__, __add__, __and__, __call__, __class__, __envir__, __eq__, __floordiv__, __ge__, __get__, __getcm__, __getitem__, __getslice__, __getsm__, __gt__, __i__, __iadd__, __iand__, __idiv__, __ijsmod__, __ilshift__, __imatmul__, __imod__, __imul__, __in__, __init__, __ior__, __ipow__, __irshift__, __isub__, __ixor__, __jsUsePyNext__, __jsmod__, __k__, __kwargtrans__, __le__, __lshift__, __lt__, __matmul__, __mergefields__, __mergekwargtrans__, __mod__, __mul__, __ne__, __neg__, __nest__, __or__, __pow__, __pragma__, __proxy__, __pyUseJsNext__, __rshift__, __setitem__, __setproperty__, __setslice__, __sort__, __specialattrib__, __sub__, __super__, __t__, __terminal__, __truediv__, __withblock__, __xor__, abs, all, any, assert, bool, bytearray, bytes, callable, chr, copy, deepcopy, delattr, dict, dir, divmod, enumerate, filter, float, getattr, hasattr, input, int, isinstance, issubclass, len, list, map, max, min, object, ord, pow, print, property, py_TypeError, py_iter, py_metatype, py_next, py_reversed, py_typeof, range, repr, round, set, setattr, sorted, str, sum, tuple, zip} from './org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js';
var __name__ = '__main__';

//# sourceMappingURL=translate2JS.map
```

Now, in terminal, if I go to the same directory (main/static/main/js/translate2JS), and type python -m transcrypt -b -m -n translate2JS.py, it actually works, and the translate2JS.js file ends up looking like the following:

```
// Transcrypt'ed from Python, 2018-10-24 00:16:44
import {AssertionError, AttributeError, BaseException, DeprecationWarning, Exception, IndexError, IterableError, KeyError, NotImplementedError, RuntimeWarning, StopIteration, UserWarning, ValueError, Warning, __JsIterator__, __PyIterator__, __Terminal__, __add__, __and__, __call__, __class__, __envir__, __eq__, __floordiv__, __ge__, __get__, __getcm__, __getitem__, __getslice__, __getsm__, __gt__, __i__, __iadd__, __iand__, __idiv__, __ijsmod__, __ilshift__, __imatmul__, __imod__, __imul__, __in__, __init__, __ior__, __ipow__, __irshift__, __isub__, __ixor__, __jsUsePyNext__, __jsmod__, __k__, __kwargtrans__, __le__, __lshift__, __lt__, __matmul__, __mergefields__, __mergekwargtrans__, __mod__, __mul__, __ne__, __neg__, __nest__, __or__, __pow__, __pragma__, __proxy__, __pyUseJsNext__, __rshift__, __setitem__, __setproperty__, __setslice__, __sort__, __specialattrib__, __sub__, __super__, __t__, __terminal__, __truediv__, __withblock__, __xor__, abs, all, any, assert, bool, bytearray, bytes, callable, chr, copy, deepcopy, delattr, dict, dir, divmod, enumerate, filter, float, getattr, hasattr, input, int, isinstance, issubclass, len, list, map, max, min, object, ord, pow, print, property, py_TypeError, py_iter, py_metatype, py_next, py_reversed, py_typeof, range, repr, round, set, setattr, sorted, str, sum, tuple, zip} from './org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js';
var __name__ = '__main__';
export var tempFunc = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        navigator.move ('right');
    }
};

//# sourceMappingURL=translate2JS.map
```

Something about running the command in the Python script is throwing Transcrypt's functionality off. Does anyone know what the problem is and if there is a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question! I tried searching for more general os.system issues instead of Transcrypt issues specifically, and I learned something. As discussed [here](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-os-system-and-subprocess-call-in-Python), os.system is not the way to do this. The newer and more powerful **subprocess** module provides greater control over how commands are executed. So:

add the line

```
import subprocess
```

and change the following:

```
os.system('python -m transcrypt -b -m -n <fileToTranslate>.py')
```

to:

```
subprocess.call('python -m transcrypt -b -m -n <fileToTranslate>.py')
```